# RSA example that do not use NoPadding

Tags: java, security, encryption, rsa

Where can I find a RSA encrypt example that does **not** use "NoPadding"?

**--update**

Better: how to make this SSCCE run correctly without throw the *"too much data for RSA block"* exception?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

/**
 * Basic RSA example.
 */
public class TestRSA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 byte[] input = new byte[100];

 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding", "BC");
 KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

 // create the keys

 RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger("d46f473a2d746537de2056ae3092c451",
  16), new BigInteger("11", 16));
 RSAPrivateKeySpec privKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(
  "d46f473a2d746537de2056ae3092c451", 16), new BigInteger("57791d5430d593164082036ad8b29fb1",
  16));

 RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
 RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);

 // encryption step

 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

 byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input);

 // decryption step

 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);

 byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

    }
}
```

**--update: about loop**

Using:

```
 byte[] cipherText = new byte[input.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
     byte[] singleByteArray = new byte[] { input[i] };
     cipherText[i] = cipher.doFinal(singleByteArray)[0];
 }
```

does not work fine. For a unknown reason the cipherText became full of zeros - even if the input is an array of 0x03.

Comment: So an example that uses a padding scheme?

Comment: @Baddle question updated

Comment: well, did you try calling just `getInstance("RSA")` ? Do you actually need BC for this?

Comment: @Bozho yes I tryied, and the same fail occur. About the BC, I don't know, I never work with cryptography before, I got this example from a book. If you have same link for me I would be thankful.

Comment: Your latest update truncates the ciphertext. Try decrypting the full array instead. Also, since your current key only allows to encrypt messages of the size of about 6 or fewer bytes, it would be helpful if you used a key with a larger modulus.

Comment: @Accipitridae by decrypting the full array we beck to the begin of this question. And about the size, I would like the rsa to encrypt any size, not just a maximum specified. After solve this I will enlange the size for the final use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Sun Providers Documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider) for the SunJCE provider tells you what padding specifications are allowed in the Cipher.getInstance() argument. Try `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");`

EDIT:
   It is not a padding issue, it is more that you have a misunderstanding of how RSA is used in cryptography. You can either 1) make the modulus bigger than the data, 2) use a [Hybrid cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), or 3) least desirable is to manually break up the input into chunks that are each smaller than the modulus. If you are going to use PKCS1 padding (which is generally recommended), then the input must be not larger than n-11 bytes in length, where n is the number of bytes needed to store the RSA modulus.

Comment: I tryied this, but I get the same fail.. please, see my update.

Comment: Yes, because you are using RSA wrong. You can't RSA encrypt a value bigger than the modulus. Unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: Modulus length in bytes minus 11 is the maximal length for the message in PKCS #1.

Comment: considering a variable data length, the best would be break the input into chunks...

Comment: I've never worked with cryptography before. The correct way to do this is a loop around the cipher.doFinal()?

Comment: Breaking the input into chunks is not a good solution. Usually one would encrypt the message with an symmetric cryptosystem and encrypt the key for the symmetric cryptosystem with RSA.

Comment: @Accipitridae that's what I'll do after correctly use RSA. The RSA will encrypt a key.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
 byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(content);
```

**Update:** Are you sure you need bouncycastle for this? And why not just pass `RSA` as argument to `Cipher.getInstance(..)` ?

**Update 2:** Why don't you try any of these [RSA encryption examples](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java+rsa+encryption+example&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_enBG314BG344&ie=UTF-8&aq=1&oq=java+rsa+enc)?

Comment: Passing just RSA to Cipher.getInstance() occur the same fail. This code is a adaptation (a try) from a book example.

Comment: so, you can try getting rid of "BC". The default provider also supports RSA.

Comment: are you sure your keys are correctly generated? Have you used `KeyPairGenerator` ?

Comment: I can't see a problem in a hex value. But they might be of wrong length for example. Use a `KeyPairGenerator` to make new keys and try.

Comment: looks like works fine with little size data. What about large size? I'm not finding examples..